# How to configure Spring Boot to use OIDC while app is behind an SSL termination proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect

I am trying to configure a Spring Boot app to use OIDC. The server is behind an SSL termination proxy.

Here are the properties I use:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            authorization-uri: https://example.org/oidc/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://example.org/oidc/oauth2/access_token
            user-info-uri: https://example.org/oidc/oauth2/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://example.org/oidc/oauth2/connect/jwk_uri
            custom-params: param_name1,param_value1,param_name2,param_value2,nonce,123456789
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: myclientid
            client-secret: myclientsecret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - openid
              - email
              - profile
            redirect-uri: https://mydomain/myapp/login/oauth2/code/oidc
```

Here's where it goes wrong:

**1. The OIDC server requires a nonce param to be added to the request URL**

I have solved this by using a custom OAuth2AuthorizationRequest that reads the custom-params property and appends those values to the request URL

**2. The OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider throws an exception caused by invalid_redirect_uri_parameter**

I have tried many approaches to fix this.

I have tried creating a filter that adds the X-Forwarded-Proto to the request (because the proxy doesn't handle that).

The headers are added, I have also added the following properties:

```
server:
    forward-headers-strategy: native
    tomcat.protocol-header: x-forwarded-proto
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider still throws an exception because this condition is false:

```
!authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri().equals(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())
```

I have debugged the code and the only difference is one being http and the other https.

*I have found a VERY hacky solution that I don't like at all, which is another filter that modifies the URL just for that particular URL.*

I would prefer a more elegant solution.

**3. When using the custom nonce parameter, the OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider throws an exception cause by invalid_nonce**

Now I am stuck. I considered writing my own Authentication Provider, but I have no guarantee that mine will be picked up before the OIDC one provided by Spring.

And with the nonce, it's a catch 22:

- if I don't use the custom param, I couldn't find a way to make Spring add the nonce to the request
- if I use that one, Spring doesn't recognize it when it's part of the JWT and freaks out

**Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as this has been driving me nuts for days if not weeks.**

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The 2 urls that are compared in case 2 come from:

- OAuth2AuthorizationRequest
- OAuth2AuthorizationResponse

***OAuth2AuthorizationRequest*** is built in the
OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter at the following line:

```
OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
```

The redirect uri is built in DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.expandRedirectUri() which calls

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request))
```

***OAuth2AuthorizationResponse*** is built in the OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication() which also calls

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request))
```

and then

```
OAuth2AuthorizationResponseUtils.convert(params, redirectUri)
```

I will double check, but I don't remember UriComponentsBuilder.adaptFromForwardedHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) being called when building these URLs.

And even if that works, that still leaves the nonce issue :(

Comment: When you say `x-forwarded-proto` didn't work, have you verified that your proxy is sending that header? If you have verified that proxy is sending that header, Can you make the `x` Capital (I know header names are case-insensitive but `adaptFromForwardedHeaders` uses `X` so just incase)

Comment: you can put a breakpoint in `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.adaptFromForwardedHeaders(HttpHeaders headers)` method as it is the method seems to be the one extracting redirect uri

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai header is set as X-Forwarded-Proto. Check my edited post about the redirect url.

Comment: When you say X-forwarded-proto didn't work, have you verified that your proxy is sending that header? I can't find the answer to this question. `because the proxy doesn't handle that.`  by that do you mean proxy is not adding that  header?

Comment: The proxy is NOT sending the header, which is why I created a filter to add the header. Apparently it works in another project, but that one isn't using Spring Boot and the latest Spring Security, and it's handling the OIDC authentication manually.

Comment: So regarding the scheme, it is a proxy issue not a spring-security's issue. May be you should raise a question tagged with proxy-name as to why it is not sending those headers?

Comment: I can't control what the proxy does. It's not handled by my team/organization. And even if I fixed that (as mentioned, I hacked some kind of fix already, but I would prefer something more standard), I still have the nonce issue (no 3).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217136/discussion-between-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai-and-ccc).

Answer (score 3):

We stumbled upon the same problem , the problem was mainly because our server was behind a reverse proxy, and it seems the proxy changed the url somehow causing this check to fail

```
!authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri().equals(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())
```

this line was removed in later versions of spring security , at commit

> 24500fa3ca23aa23ede86dfcfe02113671d5b8bc

[commit at github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/24500fa3ca23aa23ede86dfcfe02113671d5b8bc)

which was introduced on Dec 6, 2019 and was in spring security release 5.1.13

so the solution was to upgrade spring boot to at least 2.1.17 for spring boot 2.1.X line of versions.

while the OP said he can't upgrade his libraries, I hope this can help those who can.

We also did the solution mentioned above by Kavithakaran Kanapathippilla and configured our reverse proxy to add X-forwarded-proto http headers , also i believed we configured spring boot application.properties to check for them

[spring boot documentation for working behind proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server)